# C# AI for Paddle

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the computer's paddle move. I have set up the player's paddle using a mouse. This is what I have to move the paddle using mouse. How do I make the computer's paddle move where the ball is going (with chances that the computer will lose)? Cheers!

Form.Cs

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        controller.MoveLeftPaddle(e.Location.Y);
    }
```

Controller.Cs

```
    public void MoveLeftPaddle(int newPlayerPosition)   
    {
        paddlePlayer.MovePlayerPaddle(newPlayerPosition);
    }
```

Paddle.CS

```
    public void MovePlayerPaddle(int newYPosition)
    {
        position.Y = newYPosition;   
    }
```

Now, I have this code that I tried to make the computer's paddle move.

Paddle.CS

```
    public void MoveComputerPaddle(int newY2Position)
    {
        position.Y = newY2Position;   
    }
```

Controller.Cs

```
    public void MoveRightPaddle(int newComputerPosition)
    {
        if (ball.Position.Y >= paddleComputer.Position.Y)
        {
            newComputerPosition += BALLSPEED;
        }
        else if (ball.Position.Y <= paddleComputer.Position.Y)
        {
            newComputerPosition -= ball.Velocity.Y;
        }
    }

    public void Run()
    {
       MoveRightPaddle(paddleComputer.Position.Y);    
    } //im not really sure about this part. this is the only way that I didnt get squiggly line.
```

then I have a method in Controller.cs to make the ball move,bounce and draw. I use it as well to draw the paddle which is inside the method Run(). Code above

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking; are you asking on how to _implement_ the movement of the computer's paddle or what a _strategy_ would be for the behaviour of a computer opponent?

Comment: Why did you post MovePlayerPaddle twice? And where is the code for MoveLeftPaddle?

Comment: Code for MoveLeftPaddle is

        public void MoveLeftPaddle(int newPlayerPosition)
        {
            paddlePlayer.MovePlayerPaddle(newPlayerPosition);
        }

Comment: penguin, try and edit your question to include the code. I also noticed you have MoveRightPaddle twice in there as well. It is easier to debug code when we don't have to see code twice.

Comment: It looks odd that you pass in `paddleComputer.Position.Y` to `MoveRightPaddle` only to access `paddleComputer.Position.Y` in there. Also, `MoveRightPaddle` only modifies the local argument.

Comment: sorry. editing now. kinda new here.

Comment: You probably need to implement an acceleration gradient for the computer paddle with some simulated momentum of the paddle so that it appears to be a real-world object operated by a person. You could then adjust the acceleration and mass constants to suit the desired behaviour you want. You'd then be able to introduce a small degree of error to where your point of acceleration is to provide the "probability" of missing. That two would need to be adjusted with trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your paddles for the Computer and the Player would be the same, and you would have a separate controller for each - The PlayerController would take user input and call MovePaddle based on that, wheras the ComputerController would check the ball position to decide how to call MovePaddle.

You could make the ComputerController store the position for the previous X frames, allowing you to tweak difficulty simply by choosing how old the data is that it uses for its decisions.

Comment: I would also suggest trying to move towards the ball, but overlay one-dimensional [Perlin noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) (or something similar) to make the movement more 'natural'.

Comment: Do you mean overlay the noise over the ball location when analysing where to move? If so that's a nice little touch

Comment: Either that or add the noise to the 'perfect' position of the paddle, the outcome should be similar.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't read the question properly and didn't realize they were passing the optimal position to the paddle - that'd work better than doing it during analysis

Answer (score 0):

As **500 - Internal Server Error** has pointed out in the comment section, you are only changing the passed in parameter's value (in this case, `newComputerPosition`), not `paddleComputer.Position.Y`.

I don't think you need any parameters at all for `MoveRightPaddle` like so:

```
public void MoveRightPaddle()
{
    if (ball.Position.Y >= paddleComputer.Position.Y)
    {
        paddleComputer.Position.Y += BALLSPEED; // I don't know why this uses a different value from the else statement
    }
    else 
    {
        paddleComputer.Position.Y -= ball.Velocity.Y;
    }
}
```

and

```
public void Run()
{
   MoveRightPaddle();    
}
```

However, I am sensing there is a code smell somewhere if you are calling these variables directly, and thus I would suggest looking into ways of addressing this issue.

**How to make the right paddle better at moving**

Currently, your right paddle will continue follow the ball regardless of whether the ball is heading towards it or not, or if the paddle will go out of bounds or not.

If you know the `x direction` of the ball, you can quickly assert whether the right paddle even needs to move or not.

For instance:

```
 if (ball_x_direction > 0) // because for the ball to go right, the direction needs to be positive
 {
     // move paddle here:
 }
```

For checking if the paddle is going to go off screen (only showing for top of screen (i.e. the second condition of `MoveRightPaddle`)):

```
if (paddleComputer.Position.Y - ball.Velocity.Y < 0)
    paddleComputer.Position.Y = 0;
} else {
    paddleComputer.Position.Y -= ball.Velocity.Y;
}
```